# How to get the broker pool limit in celery?

Tags: celery

I have tried to set my broker pool limit to 0, but there are so many different versions of this setting, (`broker_pool_limit`, `BROKER_POOL_LIMIT`, and `CELERY_BROKER_POOL_LIMIT`) that I have no idea if it's working. Can I get this using python, or maybe the `celery inspect` tool?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Celery 4.0 and above, use the `broker_pool_limit`. You can see more about old setting names (all upper-case), and "new" (4.0 is few years old) ones in the "[New lowercase settings](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings)" of Celery documentation. If you use version older than v4.0, then use `BROKER_POOL_LIMIT`.

You can get this configuration parameter using the inspection API either from command-line, with `inspect conf` or from Python using the inspect API directly.